# Split a String in Standard C without strtok() and strsep()?

Tags: c, string

Let's say that we have the following:

```
char mystring[PMAX];
char strncpy( mystring, "hello;this;is;my;string;how;are kljasdf; you?" , PMAX);
```

Split a String in Standard C without strtok() and strsep()? 
Which reliable, portable or universal on any C standard, would you recommend to return the given part of the string?

Let' say:

```
strncpy( myoutput, strsplit( mystring, ';' , 6), PMAX );
```

The content of myoutput would be how (<- which is the sixth one, with ';' delimiter).

The best would be to have just these and only to be readily portable on any machine(s):

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
```

I am looking forward to hearing you.

Comment: Parse the string "manually". Character by character.

Comment: Use one of `strspn()`, `strcspn()` or `strpbrk()`?

Comment: Do you want the input string modified or not?  Functions like `strtok()` and `strsep()` modify the string that is being parsed, zapping the delimiter with a null byte and not telling you what character was there even if there could be any one of a number of characters marking the end of the string.  The `strcspn()` and `strpbrk()` functions give you the position of the delimiter without modifying the source string. From your proposed usage, it appears that the code in `strsplit()` should replace the sixth semicolon with a null and report the character after the fifth semicolon. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ What should happen if there isn't a fifth semicolon?  A sixth semicolon?  (In the latter case — five semicolons only — you can probably return the pointer to the start and use the null for the end of the string.)  Should the code zap each semicolon, or only the sixth?  How will your calling code know whether there was any data after the sixth semicolon? All of this stuff can be handled — it isn't even particularly hard, and there are several possible ways to do it. But you need to know what's wanted before writing any code. (Of course, designs can change after a first pass.)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing beats a state machine for predictable parsing.